# In Biometric Prompt Dialog biometric icon is not showing in Android 11

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

Android device Mi 10T and android version is 11

On click of button biometric prompt dialog is showing but biometric icon is not showing in that prompt dialog.

Below is Biometric Dialog's code

```
BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
   .setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.login))
                   .setSubtitle(activity.getString(R.string.using_your_bimetric_credential))
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                    .setConfirmationRequired(false)
                    .build();
            executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(Objects.requireNonNull(activity));
            biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt((FragmentActivity) activity,
                    executor, biometricPromptCallback);
            biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Check the device supports for biometric authentication
 */
private void checkBiometricSupport() {
    Boolean isBiometricSupported = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);
        switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:
                Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.");
                isBiometricSupported = true;
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.");
                isBiometricSupported = false;
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.");
                isBiometricSupported = false;
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:
                isBiometricSupported = false;
                // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
                final Intent enrollIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL);
                enrollIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                        BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL);
                biometricEnrollResultLauncher.launch(enrollIntent);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
            showToast("Fingerprint authentication has not been enabled in settings. ");
            isBiometricSupported = false;
        }

        if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            showToast("Fingerprint authentication permission is not enabled. ");
            isBiometricSupported = false;
        }
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)) {
            showToast("Fingerprint is not supported ");
            isBiometricSupported = false;
        }
    }

    if (isBiometricSupported) {
        dialogBioMetricPrompt();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes device supports for biometric authentication, only problem is not showing icon of biometric in center of dialog